# Fourier Series Coefficient of a given signal

Tags: integration, summation, fourier-series, signal-processing

$$
{\rm x}\left(t\right)
=
\sum_{k = -\infty}^{\infty}\left[\delta\left(t-\dfrac{k}{3}\right) + \delta\left(t-\dfrac{2k}{3}\right)\right]
$$

I need to find the Fourier series coefficient of x(t).
I know that

$$
a_{k}
=
\frac{1}{T}\int_{0}^{T}{\rm x}\left(t\right)\,{\rm e}^{-{\rm i}kw_{0}t}\,{\rm d}t
$$

but I couldn't substitute my signal into this formula.
Need some help, thanks.

Comment: You mean $n$ instead of $k$ in the first formula ? Then you could take a look at the _Dirac comb_: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_comb

Comment: Yes I have corrected it. Thanks for the link but I still can't substitute my signal into formula since in Dirac comb it says delta(t-kT) but I have delta(t-k/3). I'm a little bit confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to "impulse train", I guess I find the answer.

If $x(t)=\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}\delta(t-kT)$

$a_k = \frac{1}{T} \int_{-T/2}^{T/2} \delta(t) e^{-jkw_0t} dt = \frac{1}{T} $

Therefore in my question,
$$x(t)=\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}\delta(t-\dfrac{k}{3}) + \delta(t-\dfrac{2k}{3})$$

$$x(t)=\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}\delta(t-\dfrac{k}{3})+\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}\delta(t-\dfrac{2k}{3})$$

T = 1/3 for the first part and T = 2/3 for the second part. It follows that:
$$a_k = 3 \int_{-1/6}^{1/6} \delta(t) e^{-jkw_0t} dt + \frac{3}{2} \int_{-2/6}^{2/6} \delta(t) e^{-jkw_0t} dt $$
$$a_k =3 + \frac{3}{2} = \frac{9}{2}$$

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert #1 \right\vert}%
 \newcommand{\yy}{\Longleftrightarrow}$
$\ds{%
{\rm x}\left(t\right)
=
\sum_{k = -\infty}^{\infty}\left[\delta\left(t-\dfrac{k}{3}\right) + \delta\left(t-\dfrac{2k}{3}\right)\right]}$

> $$
> {\rm x}\left(t + T\right)
> =
> \sum_{k = -\infty}^{\infty}\left\{%
> \delta\left(t - {k - 3T \over 3}\right) + \delta\left(t - {2\bracks{k - 3T/2} \over 3}\right)
> \right\}
> $$
> which clearly shows that $T = 2$: ${\rm x}\pars{t}$ is a $\it\mbox{periodic function}$ of $\it\mbox{period}\ T = 2$. In addition, $\left.\mbox{a}\right)~{\rm x}\pars{t}$ is an $\it\mbox{even}$ function of $t$ and
> $\left.\mbox{b}\right)~{\rm x}\pars{t} \in {\mathbb R}\,,\ \forall t$. It means that
> $$
> {\rm x}\pars{t} = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}a_{n}\cos\pars{\omega_{n} t}
> \,,\quad\omega_{n} = n\,{2\pi \over T} = n\pi\quad\mbox{and}\quad
> a_{n} \in {\mathbb R}\,,\ \forall\ n = 0, 1, 2, \ldots
> $$
> $$
> \int_{-1^{-}}^{1^{+}}{\rm x}\pars{t}\cos\pars{\omega_{n}t}\,\dd t
> =
> \sum_{m = 0}^{\infty}a_{m}\ \overbrace{\quad%
> 2\int_{0}^{1^{+}}\cos\pars{\omega_{n}t}\cos\pars{\omega_{m}t}\,\dd t\quad}
> ^{\ds{\delta_{nm}}}
> = a_{n}
> $$

\begin{align}
a_{n}
&=
\sum_{k = -\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-1^{-}}^{1^{+}}\delta\pars{t - {k \over 3}}
\cos\pars{n\pi t}\,\dd t
+
\sum_{k = -\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-1^{-}}^{1^{+}}\delta\pars{t - {2k \over 3}}
\cos\pars{n\pi t}\,\dd t
\\[3mm]&=
\sum_{k = -\infty}^{\infty}\Theta\pars{3 - \verts{k}}
\cos\pars{n\pi\,{k \over 3}}
+
\sum_{k = -\infty}^{\infty}
\Theta\pars{{3 \over 2} - \verts{k}}\cos\pars{n\pi\,{2k \over 3}}
\\[3mm]&=\braces{%
1 + 2\bracks{\cos\pars{n\,{\pi \over 3}} + \cos\pars{n\,{2\pi \over 3}}
+ \cos\pars{\pi n}}}
+
\bracks{1 + 2\cos\pars{n\,{2\pi \over 3}}}
\end{align}

> $$\color{#0000ff}{\large%
> a_{n}=
> 2\braces{%
> \bracks{1 + \cos\pars{n\pi}} + \cos\pars{n\pi \over 3} + 2\cos\pars{2n\pi \over 3}}}
> $$